# Can't manage to make jpa work with glassfish and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

First of all i had to rename my entity class from Employee to EMPLOYEE because for whatever reason i had the error `Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'EMPLOYEE' does not exist`, i am using this class Employee, later renamed EMPLOYEE

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

@Id
private int id;
private String name;
private long salary;

public Employee(){}
public Employee(int id){this.id=id;}

// getters, setters
}
```

and this is the persistence xml

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="EmployeeService" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<!--<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
-->
<class>jpa.Employee</class>
    <properties>

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpa00"/> 
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/> 
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123"/>

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I am using a schema called `jpa00` containing a table `Employee` with 3 columns: a primary key, unsigned, not null, int`id`; a varchar `name`, and an int `salary`.
The rest of the code uses a utility class called EmployeeServices

```
public class EmployeeTest {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    EntityManagerFactory emf =
        Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("EmployeeService");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EmployeeService service = new EmployeeService(em);

    // create and persist an employee
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Employee emp = service.createEmployee(158, "John Doe", 45000);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println("Persisted "+emp);

    // find specific employee
    emp = service.findEmployee(158);
    System.out.println("Found "+emp);

    // find all employees
    List<Employee> list = service.findAllEmployees();
    for(Employee y:list)
        System.out.println(y);

    // update the employee
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    emp = service.raiseEmployeeSalary(158, 1000);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println("Updated "+emp);

    // remove an employee
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    service.removeEmployee(158);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println("Removed employee 158");

    // close the Em and EMF when done
    em.close();
    emf.close();

}
```

When i change the entity class from Employee to EMPLOYEE and i run this i have an output of the first operation `System.out.println("Persisted "+emp);` and right after that i have this error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Entity bean class: class jpa.EMPLOYEE, please verify that this class has been marked with the @Entity annotation.` That class has @Entity annotation, so i don't get what i am doing wrong. I have using NetBeans 8.1 and i have imported into the Libraries *EclipseLink JPA 2.1* and `MySQL JDBC Driver`. I am really out of ideas on what am i supposed to do and the all capitalized Employee issue, i just don' understand how it's that possible.

Answer (score 0):

First; you are trying to connect to MySql with Oracle Driver. Oracle and mysql have different drivers, edit your persistence.xml to set mysql driver

Second; @Table annotation may help for class name and table name match(You need that if your mysql configuration have case sensitive table names)

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE") 
public class Employee {
```

Comment: if i keep the class Employee and add @Table(name="EMPLOYEE") below @Entity i have the same error `Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'EMPLOYEE' does not exist.` I changed  the value of driver in persistence.xml to `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` as this [link](https://gist.github.com/halyph/2990769) but i still have the same problem. PS: I don't understand where the call for EMPLOYEE capitalized comes

Comment: Hibernate generates SQL as uppercase table and field names. So if you enabled your database as case sensitive(it seems yes) create tables and fields with uppercase.

Comment: I had to do a workaround in mySQL, since i'm using windows i was unable to create uppercase tables, i had to add `lower_case_table_names = 2` to the _my.ini_ file. Then i was able to create table with uppercase like _Person_ for example. I just renamed the table in MySQL `EMPLOYEE`, i have the same problem